# Task Manager Windows 8: icon disappears in document item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-8, taskmanager

This problem happens only on windows 8 inside the Task Manager.

The Windows 8 Task Manager has a grouping function for applications, even if there is only one instance of the application running.

The top line shows the application name with the application icon to the left. If you click on the right pointing triangle to the left of the application icon, you can see however many instances of the application run. The text changes from the application name to that of the caption bar of the main document.

The problem that I have is that the icon, which should be the form icon, which shows nicely, disappears from the document instance. When I first click on the triangle, the icon for the document line shows fine. After several seconds, presumably after the refresh, the icon changes to a generic Windows icon. The text is fine.

What can cause this problem and how do I resolve it? The icon displays fine on the application caption bar of the main form and the application icon is fine as well.

Windows 7 does not have this issue, as it uses a different task manager.

Comment: I have written multiple C# WinForms applications and none of them exhibit this issue on Windows 8 Task Manager.

Is your application using an icon resource with both a 16x16 and a 32x32 icon image?

Comment: And have you assigned your application icon to your main form's Form.Icon property?

Comment: Yes, that is how you assign the icon. No? You go to the designer view and select the Icon property and specify the icon. With respect to the other question, I have two different versions, and an trying to get the Designer to show, so that I can tell which one, but my other task is giving me momentary grief, so stay tuned on that.

Comment: Did you get this solved? If not, what happens if you assign the icon through code instead of in the designer?  In the Form_Load event include `this.Icon = Properties.Resources.TheNameOfTheIcon`

Comment: I will comment soon, hopefully today. THank you for asking. I got sidetracked trying to get a x64 but still keeping x86. That led to a db programming issue, but that is almost solved.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but had issues perfecting the x64/x86 build using the same source base. The x64 compilation of my code displays he icon perfectly, whereas the x86 compilation of the exact same .Net Framework based application does not. The first line shows the icon nicely, whereas the opened up line showing the actual instance of the application shows the generic windows icon. It appears that the problem is x86 (32-bit) related.

Comment: The next step to resolve this issue seems to create, hopefully, as small a project as possible, which replicates the problem in x86 mode and still works in x64 mode. Hopefully, I will know more then.